# Can you specify the tag to pull when doing a docker-compose pull?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that kind of looks like this:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  service1:
    image:service-one-image:develop
```

I know that develop is the specified tag that will be pulled if I do a docker-compose pull. But I would like to be able to pull a different tag without having the change every tag (they're all develop, so I could do a find and replace) in the yml file each time I need to switch tags. Is there a way to do that? Like a `docker-compose pull --tag=release`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible! I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49293967/how-to-pass-environment-variable-to-docker-compose-up/50991623#50991623)

Basically you change the compose file to have a variable

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  service1:
    image:service-one-image:$TAG
```

And on the command line you run `TAG={value} docker-compose {command}`