# CLI: Pass command to docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml (simplified example):

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  server:
    image: node:lts-slim
    container_name: example-container
    hostname: example-server
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    working_dir: /server
    volumes:
      - ./someLocalDirectory:/server
    command: node --watch index.js
```

I create/start the container with `docker-compose up -d server`

**Problem:**
I'd prefer to not have `command: node --watch index.js` *hardcoded* inside the yml file.

**Question:**
Is it possible to pass `command: node --watch index.js` as an argument to `docker-compose up -d server` on the command line?

Thanks in advance :)

---

**Solution:**
You can prepend key-value-pairs on the command-line and treat them like regular variables inside docker-compose:

`key="node --watch index.js" docker-compose up -d server`

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  server:
    # ... see example above
    command: ${key}
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991623/1054981)

Comment: I think the best you can do is to have your command in an `.env` file

Comment: Can you just run `node --watch index.js`, without involving Docker at all?  It seems like with this setup you want to provide the command interactively, and the code only lives on the host system; the only thing you're using Docker for is as an indirect way to get the Node interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options:

### `run`:

You can use `docker-compose run` to run commands against a service.

For example:

```bash
docker-compose run server node --watch index.js
```

Note: container stops when command exits.
See also: [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/)

### `exec`:

You can use `docker-compose exec` to run commands in a running container.

1. To start and keep your `server` running:

```
services:
  server:
    [..]
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

2. Start service:

```bash
docker-compose up -d server
```

3. Run commands:

```bash
docker-compose exec server node --watch index.js
```

See also: [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/)

### using an environment variable:

You can pass an env var to your docker-compose file that contains the command you want to run.

1. Pass an environment variable to `server`:

```
services:
  server:
    [..]
    command: $COMMAND
```

2. Run service:

```bash
COMMAND="node --watch index.js" docker-compose up -d server
```

See also: [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/)

Comment: The container immediately exists if I don't start anything. There are probably ways to handle that, but your suggestion unnecessarily increases complexity.

Comment: A yes, `docker-compose run` wil exit when your command has `run` 
(but will the watch command not just keep on running?)
Another solution would be to first start your server (something like `command: tail -f /dev/null`), and than you can use `docker-compose exec server <command>` to run any command you like.

Comment: Since you edited you initial post so nicely and also cover the solution, I'm marking your post as an Answer. Not sure though if I like your approach editing after I solved the problem myself... BUT as a general documentation for others, your edited post is great

Comment: I understand your reservations, I didn't catch the requirement that the container had to keep running