# Passing a variable from a gradle task to docker-compose.yml and on to the DockerFile

Tags: java, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I'm running into a weird issue when trying to pass a variable from a gradle task into my Dockerfile.

I have a build.gradle.kts file that, amongst other things, specifies the version of the jar I'm building and passes that version number into a task. That task runs the `assemble` task and then fires a command line execution to bring up docker compose:

```kotlin
...


version = "0.0.3-SNAPSHOT"

tasks {
    val dockerCompose by creating(Task::class) {
        description = "Builds app, spins up docker containers, and launches the API."
        dependsOn(assemble)

        doLast {
            // Command to run Docker Compose
            val command = "JAR_VERSION=$version; echo \$JAR_VERSION; docker-compose up --build"

            // Execute the command
            project.exec {
                commandLine("sh", "-c", command)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That docker-compose.yml defines my app service and a sidecar postgres service. I'm passing the `JAR_VERSION` environment variable in as an `ARG` to the Dockerfile:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - JAR_VERSION=$JAR_VERSION
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - database
...
```

And in my Dockerfile I'm using that argument to interpolate the name of the jar file to copy to my container:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine3.17

ARG JAR_VERSION
RUN echo "JAR VERSION: $JAR_VERSION"
COPY build/libs/matrix-animator-api-${JAR_VERSION}.jar /app.jar
#COPY build/libs/matrix-animator-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar # <-- the working hard coded string that we're replacing

CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

This all works, but after some trial and error I found that it ONLY works if I declare the JAR_VERSION environment variable when firing the gradle task. If I do it this way, everything executes fine:

```
JAR_VERSION= ./gradlew dockerCompose
```

[image]

But this feels gross and wrong. I shouldn't need to specify an environment variable when calling the gradle task. The whole point of defining this as a gradle task is to abstract those kinds of concepts and really, the only place that variable exists is IN the gradle build script.

When I try to fire the command without declaring the env variable it fails:

```
./gradlew dockerCompose
```

[image]

I'm not sure where exactly I'm going wrong. Any ideas???

Comment: Isnt that intended behavior though? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50991623/16034206

Comment: Yeah I guess, it just seems like there should be an easy way of sharing data between gradle and docker.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't feel like the correct way of doing it, or at least not a standard or idiomatic way of doing it, but here's how I got it working.

I know:

- I want to share data between the gradle build script and the docker files.
- the docker files will import environment variables provided in a `.env` file.
- the gradle build script is just a kotlin script, so I can add logic to it (vs a maven pom that's just xml)

So I moved my version number into a .env file:

```
JAR_VERSION=0.0.4-SNAPSHOT
SOMETHING_ELSE=SOME_OTHER_VAR
```

And then wrote file reading and environment variable parsing logic into the bottom of my build.gradle.kts file:

```
data class EnvironmentVariable(
    val name: String,
    val value: String
)

fun List<EnvironmentVariable>.getValue(name: String): String {
    return this.firstOrNull { it.name == name }?.value
        ?: throw MissingPropertyException("The $name variable is missing from the .env file")
}

fun readDotEnvFile(): List<EnvironmentVariable> {
    return File(".env")
        .bufferedReader()
        .use { it.readLines() }
        .map { it.split("=") }
        .map { EnvironmentVariable(it[0], it[1]) }
}
```

So now in my build file I can reference the jar version from .env:

```
val environmentVariables = readDotEnvFile()

group = "com.lightinspiration"
version = environmentVariables.getValue("JAR_VERSION")
```

and the jar version can be passed into docker via .env:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - JAR_VERSION=$JAR_VERSION
```

Which all works, but it feels weird to have to add in that file parsing to the gradle build script. It makes me feel like there's still something I'm missing or approaching incorrectly.